# PHP Regex for url

Tags: php, regex

I worked out this regex and its working close but only one more problem in that, it matches any word with more than one period (.)

For example: stuf... (got matched)

How do I limit the period to "Only allow 1 period per set of bracket" in the regex?

```
'#((\w+://)?(\w+\.)([a-z0-9\-/.?=_&%])+)#i'
```

Comment: \.{1} normally works, but I don't know php :-)

Comment: Its a preg_match to replace links in text. So perhaps filter couldn't help?

I did try {1} but if I put in, I will get error:

'#((\w+://)?(\w+\.)([a-z0-9\-/.{1}?=_&%])+)#i'

Comment: Pakito, to which RFC are you referring when asking the question about URLs? Would be good to know the protocol as well. Is this specifically for the http and https protocols?

Comment: Both actually. Something that is able to match most common urls as much as possible. Even ftp,hence the \w at the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'#((\w+://)?(\w+)(\.[a-z0-9\-/?=_&%]+)+)#i'
```

This requires a non-period-char after each period.

But I would recommend something like this:

```
'#((\w+://)?\w+(\.[a-z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-z\-]{2,}(/[\w\-./?=&%]*)?)#i'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this accepst URIs like `http://.-sample.-com` which are invalid (a dash cannot be the first character).

Comment: lol i tested on facebook with http://.-sample.-com and it accepted as a valid url as well.

Comment: @pakito: do you want to match an URL in a text or just check it's correctness?

Comment: Yes I want to match url(s) in text and create as hyperlink. Sorry if I sound unclear.

Floern: I am currently using your recommended regex and seems like working good for most urls. The only thing need to add in to the end is underscore and period.

    #((\w+://)?(\w+)(\.[a-z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-z\-]{2,}(/[\w\-/?=_.&%]*)?)#i

Comment: my bad, I added the period, but the underscore is already contained in `\w`.

Comment: Cool, I've totally forgotten \w includ underscore lol. Hey thanks Floern!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

The issue in the regex you're using is that you're using the greedy version "+" in the character class that includes your period. The regex I posted here checks for only a single perdiod in the name.

This pattern will successfully match google.com, www.google.com, and any arbitrary number of subdomains.

NOTE: [ICANN](http://www.icann.org/) recently announced that soon they will allow for any top-level domain (e.g. instead of just .com, .org, etc. they will soon allow .whatever), so you may need to adjust the last part of the regex, "{2,4}", since TLDs will soon be of arbitrary length.

Comment: Yes thanks normalo, that is (tld) something I am trying to avoid as well.

Comment: Ah, didn't know .museum was already in use. Well, that makes it a bit more challenging, because now you're essentially looking for any.combination.of.valid.characters.delimeted.by.periods.without.spaces.and.not.ending.in.a.punctuation.mark :S The challenge comes from the increase of possible false positive matches. I guess you'll just have to try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to validate URLs, why not use parse_url()? I think it's tricky to create a general regex for so many varied URL forms